# Record speakers on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, audio-recording

do you know if is possible to intercept the audio stream on win phone 7 and record what is being played on the speakers?

Alternatevely, I use a MediaElement, is there a way to get the current stream? I want to add some animations when certain frequency is hit.

thanks

Comment: Given that, the way you describe it, you would also be able to breach copyright, it is highly unlikely you can get the direct sound output of the phone. *Maybe if you play the music through XNA you could*

Comment: It is not about copyright, I just wanted to capture the sound input to create visualization streams, this includes voice when you are having a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the media as long as you know its location and can initiate a download. There is no built-in capability for automatically capturing the sound output. Assuming that MediaElement is playing a remote stream, you should know its location.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking on capturing sound and voice, from whatever the user is listening (including a phone call)

Comment: You can't record in the background. That means that phone call data is inaccessible to third-party developers.