# Windows Phone 8 Record Speaker Audio

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone-8, audio-recording

I'm making an app that allows users to play a keyboard and share their created songs with friends via audio files. How would I record the sounds coming from the app in order to accomplish this? In other words, how would I capture the sounds output by the speakers for a duration of time, and turn it into a WAV or MP3 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phone
read these series of articles

Comment: I could not find an article there that notes the ability to access the audio source in question. Did I miss something?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175122/Making-a-Voice-Recorder-on-Windows-Phone and here?

Comment: My goal is not to use the Microphone at all. I'm asking if there is a way for my app to access the audio it produces without using the microphone.

Comment: according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399139/record-speakers-on-windows-phone-7 you can't and i don't think that something was changed for WP8

Comment: Now that I look at that post again, it seems to answer my question. I'm going to try to use a MediaElement to output the audio and capture audio from it as well, but I'm skeptical of it working. Thanks!